# How to implement audit on a table using Hibernate?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm new to Hibernate and I want to audit all changes made to a table, to get logged into its Audit table.
In other words, any `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` on `TEST` table must be inserted into the `TEST_AUD` table.

I read a few articles on using dynamic audit tables that are created, but I cannot use it. The audit table must not be automatically generated.

I did not get a satisfactory article or solution to implement auditing using entities and Hibernate in SpringBoot?

Can someone please suggest a good article or provide an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use **hibernate envers**: https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/

set **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to create, create-drop or update**

or use **org.hibernate.tool.EnversSchemaGenerator**

You can audit entity or properties. If you entity name is TEST, the TEST_AUD will be automatically created.

You can also follow this article https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa for more informations.